# Подгрузка из input

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Помогите написать скрипт подгрузки текста из Input в value.
Схема такая: в один input вводишь и в другом сразу изменяется текст.
Для примера вот: https://blue.cash

Пробовал через onload, но ни чего толком не смог сделать... В JS слабоват.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заюзать событие onkeyup, как-то так :

```js
function x1change() {
  var x1 = +document.getElementById('x1value').value;
  document.getElementById('x2value').value = x1 * 2;
};

function x2change() {
  var x2 = +document.getElementById('x2value').value;
  document.getElementById('x1value').value = x2 / 2;
};
```

```html
<label for="x1value"> x1 value: </label>
<input type="numer" id="x1value" onkeyup="x1change()" />
<label for="x2value"> x2 value: </label>
<input type="numer" id="x2value" onkeyup="x2change()" />
```